# Android Layout Fragment/Activity Confusion

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, actionbarsherlock

I am making my first android application with the ActionBarSherlock.

The application will always have an action bar consisting of 3 tabs (first tab selected by default).
The app could be extended for use with a tablet.

I have been searching the web, and following the android development guides, however I am finding a few things confusing.
The first tab screen will be a list view with a list of items, onitemselected should send the user to a screen which features more details about that item.

When should I use a fragment? Should each tab be a fragment?
Or, should each tab call a new activity, which consists of fragments?
And, if using fragments, should I place them in different classes, or embed them within an activity??

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably read these two links first.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

If you plan to make an app that work on both phone and tablet. It is a good idea to use a fragment, and then use a shell activity to wrap that fragment.

Comment: That's true, using a ViewPager works also but won't be a good solution if you load Content from the AppStore, there you can't prevent a preloading of the next Page.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Fragments is mostly on ViewPager, so I am not entirely sure if it applies here.

In Android, you should use Fragments as much as possible. As a general rule of thumb, imagine you are translating the UI from phones to tablets, elements that can stay together in the same configuration should be a Fragment.

There is a Fragment subclass called ListFragment, so you might want to look into that for your first tab. (ListFragment is for Fragment like ListActivity is for Activity)

There is also a tutorial I found to deal with fragments. Did not really look into it but I hope it helps.

http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

As for ActionBar / ActionBarSherlock, I have absolutely no experience withit so someone might want to add to that.